# How to expose mysql data as a soap web service in Talend

Tags: mysql, soap, talend

I want to expose data in a mysql data source as a soap web service using Talend. How can I achieve that. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most powerful way to do so to do so is probably to build a WSDL using Talend Open ESB Studio ([Tutorial](http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=94))

Alternatively, if you don't like to use another piece of software or you prefer a quick-and-dirty solution, you can achieve this with standard Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. You just need to draw a standard Talend job which redirects your mysql data output to a tBufferOutput instance. Then, you must export your job as Axis webservice, finally deploy it in your application server [(Tutorial](http://talendforge.org/wiki/doku.php?id=doc%3aexport_as_webservice)). This way, your buffer data will be automatically exposed via web service. But it has a drawback: you cannot tune the response (ie, add labels to fields or refactor the SOAP response structure at all).